# Stop browser from telling me my local dev site is dangerous?

Tags: security, internet-explorer

Sorry I wasn't sure how best to tag this. Maybe someone can help? Or maybe this even belongs on a different site?

IE is giving me the big red screen telling me I should not proceed, but the address is one that is set in my hosts file to go to our local dev machine that we've used for years. I guess someone got the address and used it publicly in a malicious way.

Is there a way to prevent IE from showing this red screen or is my only choice just to change the local host name that I use for development?

It's super annoying because it pops up on every navigation.

Comment: Does IE say that the site is untrusted? What is the exact message IE gave?

Comment: Can you post the related error message? Or, you could capture a screenshot, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Strange... I just went to take a screenshot and now suddenly it doesn't give me the error anymore. Guess it has resolved itself for now but I will come back with a picture if it happens again.